# Invalid Conversion - Cast Exception: 'System.InvalidCastException'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have written a code that works perfectly as long as the user enters the information in correctly.  If the user does enter a number in the text box, I have an error message that tells the user data must be entered. When this happens I am getting a cast exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

I am new to this and I would appreciate any suggestions.

The exception occurs on this line:

```
intDetermineSubTotalCost(intSiteSelected, CInt(txtNumberOfNights.Text))
```

If I remove the option strict on, it will work with expected conversation,  however the project requires it to be on.

```
Dim intSiteSelected As Double
Dim intNumberOfNights As Integer
Dim blnNightsStayingIsVaild As Boolean = False
Dim blnDiscountIsSelected As Boolean = False
Dim intDiscountChoice As Integer
Dim strDiscountSelected As String = ""

'   Call a function to confirm if the Number of Nights staying is valid.
blnNightsStayingIsVaild = ValidateNightsStaying()

'   call a function to confirm a discount has been seected.
intDiscountChoice = ValidateSelectedDiscount(blnDiscountIsSelected, strDiscountSelected)

'   If number of nights staying and available discount has been selected,
'   calculate the subtotal, tax, and final cost.
If (blnNightsStayingIsVaild And blnDiscountIsSelected) Then
    intNumberOfNights = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfNights.Text)
    intSiteSelected = Me.cmbSelectASite.SelectedIndex
End If


If cmbSelectASite.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    intSiteSelected = 20D
ElseIf cmbSelectASite.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    intSiteSelected = 35D
ElseIf cmbSelectASite.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
    intSiteSelected = 55D
End If

intDetermineSubTotalCost(intSiteSelected, CInt(txtNumberOfNights.Text))


Private Function ValidateNightsStaying() As Boolean

'   This function validate the value entered for the number of nights staying in campground.
Dim intNightsStaying As Integer
Dim blnValidityCheck As Boolean = False
Dim StrNumberOfNightsErrorMessage As String =
    "Please Enter The Number Of Nights You Are Staying (1-99)"
Dim strMessageBoxTitle As String = " You Must Choose Number Of Nights"

Try
    intNightsStaying = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfNights.Text)
    If intNightsStaying > 0 And intNightsStaying < 100 Then
        blnValidityCheck = True
    Else
        MsgBox(StrNumberOfNightsErrorMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
        blnValidityCheck = True
    End If
Catch Exception As FormatException
    MsgBox(StrNumberOfNightsErrorMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
    txtNumberOfNights.Focus()
    txtNumberOfNights.Clear()
Catch execption As OverflowException
    MsgBox(StrNumberOfNightsErrorMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
    txtNumberOfNights.Focus()
    txtNumberOfNights.Clear()
Catch execption As SystemException
    MsgBox(StrNumberOfNightsErrorMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
    txtNumberOfNights.Focus()
    txtNumberOfNights.Clear()
End Try
Return blnValidityCheck

End Function
```

Comment: try this http://www.dotnetperls.com/parse-vbnet

Comment: what is `intDetermineSubTotalCost`?  The error itself is because an empty string ( `"" ` ) cant be cast to an integer.  For all user inputs use Integer.TryParse so you can handle when they type something stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this.

1. You could check that the string is not empty and validate on that.
2. Change the conversion to a TryParse which IIRC will return 0 on empty
3. If possible, change the input from a textbox to a numeric up/down control with min and max values of 1 and 99 respectively.

Comment: hey all,  I have tried to change the  code in the validate section, and  I keep getting the same result.   The best I can assume is that my problem is with this line.   intDetermineSubTotalCost(intSiteSelected, CInt(txtNumberOfNights.Text)) .   This line is written to calculate the cost of the selected site and multiply by the number of nights text box.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at something like this that would restrict them from entering non-numeric keypresses.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

'97 - 122 = Ascii codes for simple letters
'65 - 90  = Ascii codes for capital letters
'48 - 57  = Ascii codes for numbers

If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Do some input checking before your perform you calculations.
For Example A Textbox requiring Input:

```
        If txtInput.text.Contains("whatever you don't want there") Then
           MessageBox.Show("Please Enter The Correct Info")
           txtInput.Focus()
           Return
        End if
```

Or

```
        If Integer.TryParse(txtInput.Text, input) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Some Text.")
            txtInput.Focus()
            Return
        End If
```

This Stops the code crashing if there is an error and gives the user the opportunity to fix their input. Once all the input has been checked, perform your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Change your TextBox to a Masked TextBox. Allow only numbers in the mask.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx